# R - cox.zph() not returning rho values, p-values differ from examples

Tags: r, cox-regression, survival

When I run `cox.zph` on a Cox model, I get a different type of return than I am seeing everywhere else.

I tried running the following code:

```
library(survival) #version 3.1-7
library(survminer) #version 0.4.6

res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + wt.loss, data = lung)
#lung data is in the survival package and loads from there.

( test.ph <- cox.zph(res.cox) )
```

This gives my the following return:

```
         chisq df    p
age     0.5077  1 0.48
sex     2.5489  1 0.11
wt.loss 0.0144  1 0.90
GLOBAL  3.0051  3 0.39
```

However, examples elsewhere (including the one I'm am trying to follow [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/cox-model-assumptions)) return a table with a "rho" column, as below:

```
            rho chisq     p
age     -0.0483 0.378 0.538
sex      0.1265 2.349 0.125
wt.loss  0.0126 0.024 0.877
GLOBAL       NA 2.846 0.416
```

In addition, whatever it throwing this off appears to also be altering my chi-sq and p-values as well.

Furthermore, when I subsequently try to plot the Schoenfeld residuals using `ggcoxzph(test.ph)` I get the following plots:

[My Schoenfeld residual plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA4Ta.jpg)

Versus the example:

[sthda version of the same plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgTuR.png)

These issues are causing a massive block to my group's efforts on a current project, and any help offered will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I get teh same result as you. Why do you trust the results on that undated webpage that is NOT  from the package author?

Comment: Hi 42, I see that the `rho` column is included in many many examples, including from the example in the R documentation at rdrr.io

Comment: rdrr.io is NOT an up-to-date resource. And you are not being specific about where on that domain you are seeing this.

Comment: Hi 42.  <https://rdrr.io/cran/survival/man/cox.zph.html> is the webpage where I found the table I spoke of. The page says it was built on Nov 9, 2019.

Comment: see my edited answer which gives you a function based on the old version source code. Also please accept that answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: If you run sessionInfo in that rdrr.io webpage you get: R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15). So it is a year and a half out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your version of `survival` package. It works for me as it should (print method shows "rho").

I'm using version 2.43-3

EDIT: 42 was right, I was installing from an out-of-date mirror. I just updated to the latest version.

Of course one solution is you roll back your install to an older version. But assuming you don't want to do that...

It appears you will need to calculate what you want yourself. I don't know if this is the most concise way but I simply adapted the source code from the old version of the package into a function where you can pass your fitted object and your cox.zph test object.

```
library(survival) #version 3.1-7
library(survminer) #version 0.4.6

res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + wt.loss, data = lung)
#lung data is in the survival package and loads from there.

test.ph <- cox.zph(res.cox) 

your_func <- function(fit, transform = "km", new_cox.zph = NULL) {
  sresid <- resid(fit, "schoenfeld")
  varnames <- names(fit$coefficients)
  nvar <- length(varnames)
  ndead <- length(sresid)/nvar
  if (nvar == 1) {
    times <- as.numeric(names(sresid)) 
  } else {
    times <- as.numeric(dimnames(sresid)[[1]])
  }

  if (is.character(transform)) {
    tname <- transform
    ttimes <- switch(transform, identity = times, rank = rank(times), 
                     log = log(times), km = {
                       temp <- survfitKM(factor(rep(1, nrow(fit$y))), 
                                         fit$y, se.fit = FALSE)
                       t1 <- temp$surv[temp$n.event > 0]
                       t2 <- temp$n.event[temp$n.event > 0]
                       km <- rep(c(1, t1), c(t2, 0))
                       if (is.null(attr(sresid, "strata"))) 1 - km else (1 - 
                                                                           km[sort.list(sort.list(times))])
                     }, stop("Unrecognized transform"))
  }
  else {
    tname <- deparse(substitute(transform))
    if (length(tname) > 1) 
      tname <- "user"
    ttimes <- transform(times)
  }
  xx <- ttimes - mean(ttimes)
  r2 <- sresid %*% fit$var * ndead
  test <- xx %*% r2
  corel <- c(cor(xx, r2))
  cbind(rho = c(corel,NA), new_cox.zph$table)
}
```

Call the function

```
your_func(fit = res.cox, new_cox.zph = test.ph)

                rho      chisq df         p
age     -0.04834523 0.50774082  1 0.4761185
sex      0.12651872 2.54891522  1 0.1103700
wt.loss  0.01257876 0.01444092  1 0.9043482
GLOBAL           NA 3.00505434  3 0.3908466
```

**UPDATE**

I don't know about the difference in the chisq and p calculations between versions. You may want to check release notes for what changed between versions. But for your purposes, I'm not sure there will be a difference in "rho" which appears to simply be a pearson correlation between 1. difference from observation time and mean time [ttimes - mean(ttimes)] and 2. fitted values multiplied by schoenfeld residuals (scaled by number dead). From the code..

```
sresid <- resid(fit, "schoenfeld")
xx <- ttimes - mean(ttimes)
r2 <- sresid %*% fit$var * ndead
test <- xx %*% r2
corel <- c(cor(xx, r2))
##corel is rho
```

Comment: It appears my version is newer. My version is 3.1-7

Comment: The current version on CRAN is 3.1-7. version 2.43-3 is over a year out-of-date.

Comment: Hi 42 and others, I wonder if they removed this functionality for some reason?  How would I discover that? I apologize, but I am new to all of this.  I only started with R sometime in September.  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I've updated the version (was out of date on my mirror) and edited my answer

Comment: mb158127, Thanks for all the effort! I'm afraid that the chi-square and p-values are still different though. Cheers!

Comment: i addressed that in my update. The rho is probably invariant to whatever changed in those statistics. I think you need to do your own research to find out the statistics you are using - there are certainly multiple variations on these statistics and the package authors may have decided to switch to a calculation which is now accepted as being preferable for some or another reason. Usually a change like this would be noted in release notes.

Comment: Please ... both of you should read the help page for the current version of cox.zph. There is a note that says versions 3+ use a full score test replacing earlier versions that used an approximation.

Comment: basically what I already said. Please accept my answer if the rho calculation is useful. Thx!

Comment: Thanks so much to both mb158127 and 42!  You really helped me out.